# Talend tRest connection reset error sending request to https endpoint

Tags: java, rest, https, talend

I have a simple talend job (data integration) that uses a tRest component to connect to a rest service using a GET request that is outside our internal network. This works fine for a generic http URL but when using any https URL, the job 'hangs' for a while and then errors with the following:-

```
Exception in component tREST_1
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:616)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:559)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:72)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:502)
at darren_demos.test_rest2_0_1.Test_REST2.tREST_1Process(Test_REST2.java:596)
at darren_demos.test_rest2_0_1.Test_REST2.runJobInTOS(Test_REST2.java:954)
at darren_demos.test_rest2_0_1.Test_REST2.main(Test_REST2.java:811)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1705)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:122)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.kickstart(Handshaker.java:909)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1423)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1288)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler$1$1.getOutputStream(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:203)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.commitWrite(CommittingOutputStream.java:117)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:89)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)
at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:88)
at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:58)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.TerminatingClientHandler.writeRequestEntity(TerminatingClientHandler.java:305)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:182)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:129)
... 7 more
[statistics] disconnected

Job Test_REST2 ended at 15:16 11/05/2016. [exit code=1]
```

This seems to happen for any https endpoint I try. The URL's involved are accessible via a browser on same machine.

Any thoughts on the cause? I have made sure that the root certificates involved are in the cacerts file of the jre but I don't think its getting that far.

Comment: Try using tRESTClient instead, https is supported out-of-the-box! See https://help.talend.com/display/TALENDOPENSTUDIOCOMPONENTSREFERENCEGUIDE52EN/tRESTClient

Answer (score 0):

With the component **tSetKeystore** you should be able to set up your tRest component. You can enter the trust store and the key store, if neccessary, in the **tSetKeystore** component. Then use a **OnComponentOk** connection to trigger your tRest to access the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have root certificate trusted in the {JAVA_HOME}/../jre/lib/security/cacerts.

Make sure certificates have been added to to cacerts by listing added certificates.

Restart the Open Studio then try again.